# WOPI : File content is not displaying in DOC Viewer

Tags: node.js, ms-wopi

I have implemented WOPI in my Vue.js app and implemented a GET API in Node.js to return the file content, still iam unable to see the content in DOC viewer in front-end and there are no errors even, attached screenshot of UI here:
[UI DOC Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meFes.png)

The following is the action URL sample that i tried.
https://ffc-word-view.officeapps.live.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?wopisrc=https://app.maindomain.com/file/v1/wopi/files/1269474

The following is the API Code which i wrote to read a file from Azure Blob storage and to return the file content:

```js
var request = require('request');
        request.get('<FILE_BLOB_URL>',{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                  let json = JSON.stringify(body);
                  let bufferOriginal = Buffer.from(JSON.parse(json));
                  res.status(200).send(bufferOriginal)
            }else{
              console.log('WOPI Files Content Read Err is:');
                  console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone suggest me the that the way that iam returning the file content is correct or not?

Comment: I have implemented '/wopi/files/:FID' API only for time-being, to get this working do i need to implement other endpoints also which were proposed in CSPP document?

Comment: You have to implement `/wopi/files/(file_id)/contents` endpoint as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have implemented '/wopi/files/:FID' API only for time-being, to get this working do i need to implement other endpoints also which were proposed in CSPP document?

To get the View mode working, you need at least:

- [CheckFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/checkfileinfo)
- [GetFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/getfile)

To support the Edit mode, you need:

- [PutFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/putfile)
- [*Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/lock) - all locking operations